# Issue with nlevels

Tags: r, r-factor

I am trying to do something that I thought was simple but I am actually struggling to get it right. Briefly put, I have a dataframe with 3 columns: Station's name, Quadrat's name and abundance (see reproducible example below). What I would like to do is to use nlevels to know for each Station how many levels of QuadratName I have. I was expecting the results to be 2 for HA (Q1 & Q2), 3 for BA (Q2, Q3 & Q4) and 2 for CA (Q5 & Q6). However, no matter what I try, the result is always 6 for every station.
I tried to do this for HA separately (testHA) but the result was 6 as well...

Do you know why it is not working ? Am I not using nlevels correctly ?
Thank you for your help !

```
test<-data.frame("Station"=factor(c(rep("HA",3),rep("BA",3),rep("CA",3))),
                "QuadratName"=factor(c(rep("Q1",2),rep("Q2",2),"Q3","Q4",rep("Q5",2),"Q6")),
                "Ab"=c(2,5,4,7,5,2,5,3,2))


for (var in unique(test$Station)) {
  n=nlevels(test[test$Station==var,"QuadratName"])
  print(n)
}

testHA<-subset(test,test$Station=="HA")
nlevels(testHA$QuadratName)
```

Comment: Factor variables can have levels that don't actually occur in the data.

Comment: @Phil Thank you for your comment, I didn't know that! Do you have any idea how I could do what I tried to do using nlevels? Is there another function I should try?

Comment: Try with `n=nlevels(droplevels(test[test$Station==var,"QuadratName"]))`